# How can I make cars drive navigate an intersection without colliding?

Tags: 2d, algorithm, path-finding, car, collision-prediction

I'm trying to create a 2D game with a traffic intersection:

[image: top-down image of a complex intersection, with cars shown as rotated rectangles]

My car game-objects need to pass through the intersection without colliding with each other, and without stopping, if possible.

How can I implement such a behaviour?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Are you asking for an algorithm on how a car would determine whether it is safe to go? Are you asking how to use libgdx to draw the cars? etc... Being specific and succinct helps prevent your questions from being downvoted.

Comment: what i  need is an algorithm to determine the path and speed for the car to move through the intersection without collision

Comment: Are you looking for something like the second video on https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~aim/?p=video ? That site has links to papers with algorithms.

Comment: yes.that's  exactly what i'm looking for. thank you